# Probability of walking

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A beetle is moving across a cartesian coordinate . Initially it is at origin. In each move it chooses one of the four adjacent lattice points and goes to it . After $n$ moves what's the probability that it is at origin again ?

My Attempt : We know the total sample space is $4^{n}$, but can't find the numerator of the probability? Please help .

Comment: Do it by hand for $n=1,2,3,4$ and see if you can spot a pattern

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure at the moment. But here's a potential solution.

For each move that the beetle makes, it must make a countermove in the exact opposite direction. So, it has the freedom of choice in only half of the moves $(n/2)$. The other half will be determined automatically. That makes the number of distinct paths that work for us $4^{n/2}$.

Hence the required probability would be

$$P = \frac{4^{n/2}}{4^n} = \frac{1}{4^{n/2}}$$

However, since the beetle can only take full steps and not half-steps, $n/2$ must be a whole number. Meaning $n$ must be even.

If $n$ is odd, the beetle will not be able to return to the origin. So probability would be $0$.